# How to create Grid Table in C#?

Tags: c#, grid

I am trying to create a 3x3 grid table for my tic-tac-toe game.
So far I have this:

[image]

But I am trying to make it look like this:
 [image]

HERE IS MY CODE: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PnPPI.png)

Comment: What is your app type? WinForms, WPF, web? And what have you tried so far? Please show some code to us.

Comment: design and implement a class that allows a person to play a two player game of tic-tac-toe on a 3x3 grid that is a 3x3 array of integers. The default constructor should initialize all board values to the integer zero (0). When player 1 moves you should place a one (1) in the position of the array they choose to move to and when player 2 moves you should place a two (2). Each move must be to an empty square and the program should be able to correctly display when a win is achieved and who the winner is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use special Unicode chars to draw grid in console. First define your table like this:

```
var table = new[]
{
    new[] {" ", "0", "1", "2"},
    new[] {"A", null, null, null},
    new[] {"B", null, null, null},
    new[] {"C", null, null, null},
};
```

Now you can print it content with this code:

```
var rows = table.Length;
var cols = table.First().Length;
var header = $"┌{string.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat("──┬", cols - 1))}──┐";
var middle = $"├{string.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat("──┼", cols - 1))}──┤";
var footer = $"└{string.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat("──┴", cols - 1))}──┘";

Console.WriteLine(header);
for (var i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
{
    foreach (var cell in table[i])
        Console.Write($"│ {cell ?? " "}");
    Console.WriteLine("│");
    if (i < rows - 1)
        Console.WriteLine(middle);
}
Console.WriteLine(footer);
```

You can find live demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xL35He)